# Relation between ideals of a subalgebra and algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $B$ be a closed subalgebra of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$.

> Is it true that every closed ideal of $B$ is of the form $I\cap B$ for some closed ideal $I$ of $A$.

Let $i$ be natural inclusion from $B$ to $A$. Let $J$ be a closed ideal of $A$. Set,  $I=\overline{i(J)}$, closure of $i(J)$ in $B$. Does this works?

Answer (score 2):

No, $A$ can be simple and the subalgebra $B$ not simple.

Comment: +1 Thanks, do you know any nontrivial example?

Comment: Subalgebras of simple $C^*$ algebras have been studied extensively. See, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701035.

Comment: Perhaps an easier example: the reduced $C^*$-algebra of $\Bbb Z$ is not simple, but is inside the reduced $C^*$-algebra of the free group of rank $2$ which is simple.

Comment: Even simpler example: let $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, with $B=\mathbb C^2$ which sits inside $A$ as the diagonal matrices, and $J=\mathbb C\oplus0$ is an ideal in $B$.